# Recreate view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

So I'm making a game for iOS and I'm having this problem. When I'm in the GameViewController and the game ends, I present the user with a rematch option in another view controller. If the user taps rematch I want to recreate the GameViewController again, like a completely new instance, with data and views like default.

When I do:
    `GameViewController *gvc = [[GameViewController alloc]init];`
from the current view controller and I push gvc, it all works well, but memory keeps increasing since it seems that the old gvc is not being destroyed.

Is it possible to reuse the old gvc and restart it? Or if the way I do it is a better approach, how can I make the OS know that the old gvc can be released?

Comment: Are you using a NavigationController into the game?

Comment: @Napolux No, just plain UIViewController and navigate between them with segues. When the player wins or loses I present EndGameViewController modally from gvc.